# ionic: android platform add a plugin, then what i have written are gone

Tags: ionic-framework

ionic: android platform add a plugin, then what i have written are gone

i create a new ionic demo

```
>ionic start mydemo blank
>cd mydemo
>ionic platform add android
>ionic build android
```

original **index.html** in **mydemo/platforms/android/assets/www**

[original index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZWeW.png)

then i create **controllers.js** in **mydemo/platforms/android/assets/www/js**, add this js into index.html. change **h1** content: "Ionic Blank Starter" to "My Ionic Demo"

[edited index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7niM.png)

then add **cordova-sqlite-plugin**

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git
```

after plugin is installed, the **controllers.js** is gone, and **index.html** becomes the original one.

i try to install other plugins, there is the same problem.

did someone have the same issue? thank you

Comment: dude, what are you trying to say? you code written are gone means where? where you written code? in www folder or in platform folder or plugins folder ? can you please update you question properly  so we can answer you.

Comment: every code i write in "platforms/android/" is gone,  such as "res", "assets/www", and i have updated my question

Comment: yes, it will gone as always, you need to change only root www folder of ionic app please don't touch any files in platforms folder it will generated itself when you fire command ionic build or ionic plugin add etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow:

> 1. ionic start mydemo blank
> 2. cd mydemo
> 3. ionic platform add android
> 4. ionic build android

then you need to change your code in **mydemo/www** folder html/js files.

Please don't change any code in **mydemo/platforms/android/assets/www** because in **platforms/android/assets/www** will generate and controlled by cordova you don't need to touch **mydemo/platforms/android/assets/www** folder's files.

Please change **mydemo/www** files and test first.

It will help you defiantly.

And please go through ionic documentation carefully first for avoid this kind of mistake.

Thank you.

Comment: if answer help you please make it answer and do up vote so if other have same issue they can resolve it easily. Thank you. Glad to help you. Happy coading.,,